# Axios doesn't seem to be working when bundled with electron, how can I troubleshoot a compiled exe with electron?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, electron, vue-cli

I have a VUE JS app that I have created that consumes the News api endpoint:

```
import axios from "axios";
let baseURL = `https://newsapi.org/v2`;
let apiKey = process.env.VUE_APP_APIKEY;
const instance = axios.create({
    baseURL: baseURL,
    timeout: 30000,
    headers: {
        "X-Api-Key": apiKey,
    },
});
export default instance;
```

When running `npm run electron:serve` it works with the api retrieving the data.

[image: running served app]

But when I compile it with `npm run electron:build` it compiles but it looks like the axios call no longer works. I have tried removing the environment variable and adding they key direct to test and it still doesn't work. How can I troubleshoot a built exe with electron?

[image: notworking built]

The relevant bits in my package.json look like:

```
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint",
    "electron:build": "vue-cli-service electron:build",
    "electron:serve": "vue-cli-service electron:serve",
    "postinstall": "electron-builder install-app-deps",
    "postuninstall": "electron-builder install-app-deps"
  },
  "main": "background.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "core-js": "^3.6.5",
    "vue": "^2.6.11",
    "vue-router": "^3.2.0",
    "vuex": "^3.6.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-router": "^4.5.12",
    "@vue/cli-service": "~4.5.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "electron": "^11.0.0",
    "electron-devtools-installer": "^3.1.0",
    "eslint": "^6.7.2",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^6.2.2",
    "vue-cli-plugin-electron-builder": "~2.0.0-rc.6",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.11"
  },
```

Answer (score 1):

For anyone wondering, to diagnose I downloaded an app called **HTTP Toolkit** which can attach itself to the electron app and allow you to view the http(s) requests being sent.

In this case the API requests are sent from app:// and this presents a problem with CORS which is why it stopped working. Localhost was fine which was why it worked on serve but not build.